Fixing 'Connection Reset by Peer' Error When Calling bitcoind REST API in a Container
Problem: Unable to Access bitcoind REST API from Host Machine
Description: I have bitcoind installed in a container, and I can successfully make REST API calls from within the container. However, when attempting to make the same calls from my host machine, I encounter the following error:
isudoajl@f38-server:$curl localhost:8333/rest/chaininfo.json
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Configuration:
bitcoind configuration (bitcoin.conf):
server=1
rpcuser=xxxx
rpcpassword=xxxx
rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/24
rpcport=8332
rest=1
txindex=1

Container is listening on port 8333
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Verified bitcoind configuration settings.
Checked container's listening ports.
Attempted various curl commands from host machine.
Question: Is there a solution to this problem? I've been troubleshooting for days without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
